# Is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` deprecated?

Tags: x11, xorg

I think X on my machine works fine without `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Some articles say this file is now deprecated but some Unix-like distributions still teach users how to configure X with this file.

So what is the current status of this file? Should it be used or not? If it isn't deprecated, why is X able to work well without it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Traditionnaly, Xorg was not able to detect and handle all the settings automatically and relied on external intervention to adjust them.

Xorg progressively developed and improved an auto-detection feature which allowed to generate a fairly good configuration file.

That feature eventually became so efficient that it was integrated with the normal engine initialization process.

When present, the configuration file takes precedence over auto-detected settings.

Comment: To summarize, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` isn't deprecated per se, but the process of explicitly generating or writing it is deprecated. You can still write a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if you need one, but most people don't need one.