# What is the modern, up-to-date way to manually tweak X11/Xorg settings?

Tags: x11, xorg

I'm curious about this. I have heard that the usual method of tweaking X settings that I was aware of from past experience - that is, using an "xorg.conf" file has been deprecated for a while and thus could potentially disappear altogether in future versions of the X graphic system. In particular, it appears that this was done to favor the automatic configuration of X, however it seems this automatic configuration doesn't always work; in particular, I have a monitor setup that "out of the box" uses a lower resolution than the monitor is capable of and it won't allow the selection of a higher resolution given the default settings, suggesting a manual configuration would be needed. (Namely, my monitor can do 1600x900, but the current system is at 1024x768 which not only makes it less detailed but also makes it uncomfortably stretched due to the wrong aspect ratio between these two settings.)

Which then makes me wonder - is there a *current and up-to-date way* that is *not* deprecated and so likely won't disappear any time soon, to configure X manually or to tweak X settings for configurations where the autoconfiguration fails to optimally configure it? I have not found *anything* googling for this, and it seems anyone who talks about X being configured manually suggests to use xorg.conf and either the information I get is grossly outdated or it seems the authors are unaware of the deprecation.

What should I do?

Comment: See: [Is /etc/X11/xorg.conf deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333450/is-etc-x11-xorg-conf-deprecated) ... TLDR: editing xorg.conf isn't actually deprecated, but generally isn't needed because the autodetection works much better nowadays. If you do create your own xorg.conf, it will override any automatically generated settings.

Comment: You can add custom resolutions with `xrandr`. No xorg.conf needed.

Comment: You can add custom entries in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. For example, if you use a non-US keyboard, you can have a `00-keyboard.conf` file there: the systemd command `localectl` actually creates this file when you use it with the flag `set-x11-keymap`. I also put a `52-nvidia.conf` to enable Coolbits and disable the logo.