# no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file in RHEL 7

Tags: linux, xorg, graphics

I found this [Is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333450/is-etc-x11-xorg-conf-deprecated)

However it didn't shed much light on the issue.

I am trying to make use of remote desktop software (nice) and it is erroring on there not being an xorg.conf file.  For the past couple years I suppose I have been installing RHEL 7.6+ from dvd and everything seems to be working fine and all the while there not being an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

I also install Nvidia + CUDA and that squawks a little bit about xorg.conf such as when uninstalling nvidia it tries to restore the xorg.conf file it thinks it backed up but there never was one.  But Nvidia + CUDA has been working fine for me with there not being an xorg.conf file.

- So, can someone tell me what the deal is with `xorg.conf` these days in RHEL 7.9 and what to do when other software seems to require and does not work without it?
- Since `xorg.conf` is no longer there in RHEL 7.9, what takes its place?  What files do you now go look at and edit to mess with linux graphics?

Comment: Gone Wayland only ?

Comment: @user2284570 not in RHEL 7...

Answer (score 7):

X.org configuration lives in a number of places, notably `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (if it exists), and `.conf` files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. (For an exhaustive list, see `man xorg.conf` on your system.)

Most settings which used to require an `xorg.conf` file in the past are now auto-detected, and many others can be specified generically in configuration snippets, which is why most systems run without an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file at all. It’s hard to give a general answer for what to do with software which doesn’t cope well with the absence of this file; it might be sufficient to create an empty file.

To understand how your X server is configured, see the files listed in the first paragraph above, and the server logs (in `/var/log` or `~/.local/share/xorg`). As [JoL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/189744/jol) [suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663116/no-etc-x11-xorg-conf-file-in-rhel-7/663118?noredirect=1#comment1247607_663118), you can also generate a configuration file corresponding to the auto-detected configuration, by running

```
Xorg -configure :1
```

in a virtual console which *isn’t already running X*. This will leave an `xorg.conf.new` file in your home directory.

Comment: Wonder if the remote desktop software of the OP wants to parse the file for itself. Switching to another console and running `Xorg -configure :1` generates a `xorg.conf.new` file in the home directory. Maybe that's equivalent to what it auto-detects. The manpage says: "This option currently has some problems on some platforms, but in most cases it is a good way to bootstrap the configuration process. This option is only available when the server is run as root." However, despite it saying that, I was able to generate the file with a regular user.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the X server executable (`Xorg`) is setuid `root` in the Linux distributions I used. Maybe this  explains @JoL's success. I remember seeing the X server process running as `root`.

Comment: @FooF `Xorg` can run as a regular user if the display is handled by the kernel, which is generally the case nowadays. The `Xorg` binary in RHEL 7 isn’t setuid.

Comment: @StephenKitt That's great (old?) news for security!!!

Comment: @FooF somewhat old, yes ;-). The `xorg-x11-server` package was modified to drop the setuid bit from the `Xorg` binary in September 2010 (but it used capabilities, it didn’t fully run as a regular user).

Comment: Good riddance, and at least with capabilities you can put some granularity to the exposed attackable surface. The way to go!!!

Comment: And capabilities aren’t even needed any more, current packages just ship a plain binary with no special privileges at all.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that generating the file causes the server to fail with error and leave the listening socket. What that causes is that if you generate the file with root on one display, you can't later regenerate it without root for the same display, because it can't open the root-owned socket. BTW, I can confirm that my Xorg executable isn't setuid root nor does it have any capabilities set.

Comment: **FYI:** the use of `X -configure` for me was not a solution, it ended up causing my console display to not work with the `xorg.conf` file it created.  However because I have NVIDIA installed, doing `nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus --preserve-busid` created an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file which made everything work and seems to have solved my issues as far as I can tell thus far.

Comment: when I install `cuda_11.4.0_470.42.01_linux.run` from runlevel 3 it gives a simple text menu to install but it does not run `nvidia-xconfig` at the end not like when doing just a driver install like `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.57.02.run` for example where it is a little more graphical and prompts you at the very end if you want to run `nvidia-xconfig`... which if you do it creates the `xorg.conf` file behind the scenes which hadn't already been present.